# Python Regex - Get strings before and after substring

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
txt = '<li>one. URL : <a href="http://local.ru">http://local.ru</a> (10.02.2022).</li><li>Two</li><li>Three. URL : <a href="https://local.ru">https://local.ru</a> (15.11.2021).</li>'
re.findall(r'(<li>.*?)\s?URL\s?:\s?(<a.*?>).*?(</a>.*?</li>)', txt)
```

I need gen output

```
[('<li>one.', '<a href="http://local.ru">', '</a> (10.02.2022).</li>'),
 ('<li>Three.', '<a href="https://local.ru">', '</a> (15.11.2021).</li>')]
```

If without the first brackets, then it works. But it does not output the text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](/q/1732348/90527)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your regex was too generous on the `.*?`, if you limit to non-node with `[^<>]`, then you get the expected output.

```py
import re

txt = (
    '<li>one. URL : <a href="http://local.ru">http://local.ru</a> (10.02.2022).</li>'
    '<li>Two</li>'
    '<li>Three. URL : <a href="https://local.ru">https://local.ru</a> (15.11.2021).</li>'
    )

re.findall(r"(<li>[^<>]*?)\s?URL\s?:\s?(<a[^>]*?>).*?(</a>.*?</li>)", txt)
```

gives

```py
[('<li>one.', '<a href="http://local.ru">', '</a> (10.02.2022).</li>'),
 ('<li>Three.', '<a href="https://local.ru">', '</a> (15.11.2021).</li>')]
```